# Moving event handlers to separate document

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using this HTML code:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="page.html" >
Name:  <input type="text" id="name" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" id="email" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But I would like to move my event handlers into my separate javascript, into the function named initiate. My javascript looks like this:

```
function formValidator(){

    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");


    if(isAlphabet(name, "Fill in name"))
    {

        if(emailValidator(email, "Fill in email"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }


    return false;

}

function isAlphabet(elem, helpMsg)
{
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(elem.value.match(alphaExp))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(helpMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function emailValidator(elem, helpMsg)
{
    var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
    if(elem.value.match(emailExp))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(helpMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}


function initiate {
    // ..
}
window.onload = initiate;
```

So far I've only figured out how to write the code to redirect to the new webpage but it doesn't check that it is a valid code. I've used this:

HTML

```
<form id="form">
Name:  <input type="text" id="name" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" id="email" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("form").action = "page.html";
```

But I can't figure out how to write so that both the `.action="page.html"` and the `return validateForm()`is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form needs an `id` :

```
<form id="form">
Name:  <input type="text" id="name" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" id="email" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Separate Javascript file:

```
function initiate()
{
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.action = "page.html";
    form.onsubmit = function validateForm()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");


        if(isAlphabet(name, "Fill in name"))
        {

            if(emailValidator(email, "Fill in email"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    };
}

window.onload = initiate;
```

Make sure the `validateForm()` function is returning false if something didn't validate.